# getting a html content of div that is dynamically updating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've one functionality where user can save the state of Application, application consist of many visual element for this i think of storing whole html string of my workspace div

```
 <div id = "workspace">
 <div id = "playground">
   here is my all div where user drag n drop the component from left hand side 
 </div></div>
```

now i am doing

```
    var x = $("#playground").html() // to get all html content inside the playground div
alert(x)
```

now x is giving me only html code that i have written on html document not the other div that was append when user drag n drop to the playground

any body have any better solution for the auto-saving and regaining to original state please let me know

[here is the link to the application](http://59.163.223.69:20083/Simulator/industrialautomationlab/bottlefilling/index.htm)

thank you

Comment: Try using .text instead of .html ! Maybe this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a class like `.droppableThing`, to all droppables then use

`$("#playground").child('.droppableThing')`

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

```
var x = document.getElementById("playground").innerHTML;
alert (x);
```

Comment: That's the same thing in javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

“playground” is spelled “playgraound” in the HTML. `$("#playground").html()` seems to work. Could this be your problem?